# How to move ActionBar when sidebar opens?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-actionbar, sidebar

I have a `SideBar` in my android app which opens when the user clicks on a button. But in the activites which contain `ActionBar` too, when the `SideBar` opens, the `ActionBar` stays at the top while the rest of the activity moves offscreen. So how can the `ActionBar` be also moved offscreen when the `sidebar` opens?

Comment: How have you implemented the sidebar?

Comment: @rajesh it is an external library ( Scringo)

Comment: Check if your library has APIs to have a sidebar without action bar.

Comment: @rajesh No it does'nt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution would be to call `ActionBar.hide()` when you open the sidebar. The other option would be to give the ActionBar a sliding animation.

Comment: The action bar and activity should be partially visible, hiding action bar will make it invisible. Can you elaborate on the sliding animation method?

Comment: create a custom animation and have it animate your actionBar. for example pass the object(actionBar) and then calculate the max coordinates you want it to slide off the screen with the Display class. (DisplayMetrics)